# Javascript setTimeout sequence

Tags: javascript, settimeout, sequence, timing

Say I have this line of javascript-

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log("okay"); }, 5000);
/* Blah blah- more code */
```

Is that going to wait 5 seconds, run the `console.log()`, then continue on the the rest of the script?

OR

Is it going to set the `console.log()` to be ran in 5 seconds while its already went ahead and is running the rest of the code?

Comment: `setTimeout()` forks a different process so the rest of the program can continue running.

Comment: @JonathanM JavaScript engines only have a single thread, forcing asynchronous events to queue waiting for execution. They don't fork processes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout()` will set the `console.log()` to be run in 5 seconds and continue running the remaining code immediately.

In other words, `setTimeout()` calls it's target code asynchronously.